# 20 balls problem - Distribution for 3 items

Tags: probability

A box contains 20 balls numbered from 1 to 20. We take out 3 balls without putting them back later and without noting the seira we chose.

a) Find the sample space.

b) Calculate the distribution Fx(x) of the maximum index for the 3 balls(for x=1,2...,20)

c)Calculate the mass probability function Px(x).

d)If we bet that one of the three balls will have a number greater or equal to 17, what's the probability of winning the bet?

**My Attempt:**

a)The sample space was quite simple (I hope) (20*19*18)/6 = 1140 outcomes.

b)If I want to calculate the distribution for x=1,2...,20 I will have to calculate P(X<=x) for each one of them.So, I realized in my first attempt that I need to know the mass probability. But, that is the third question. Anyway, I looked at a similar problem with dice, but the dice repeat. Is Px(x)= 1/20?? At this point I tried creating an array for the outcomes. The fact that I need to calculate the maximum index confuses me.

Can someone give me a hint?Or tell me what methodology I need to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to highest index to be smaller than $x$, then the indices from our balls must all be smaller than $x$. We start by noticing that the domain of $X$ equals $D_X=\{3,4,\ldots,20\}$. For $x\in D_X$ we then have 
\begin{equation}
P(X\le x) = \binom{x}{3}/\binom{20}{3} = \frac{x!}{3!(x-3)!}\frac{3!17!}{20!} = \frac{17!x!}{20!(x-3)!} = \frac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{20\cdot19\cdot18}
\end{equation}

Comment: Oh I see. Will I have to think similarly for d) ? Will I have to calculate 1 - (16*15*14)/(20*19*18) ?

Comment: For $d$  you need to calculate $P(X\ge 17)$. Note that this equals $1- P(X<17) = 1-P(X\le 16)$, which is something we already calculated in $b$.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Marc . One last thing: for c) will i have to think that for every possible value x=1,2,3,4,5..,20 of X there is only one for each of the value. Basically 20*19*18 ?

Comment: The usual way to go is to note that $f_X(x) = F'_X(x)$, ie the mass probability function is the derivative of the cumulative distribution function.